# Proof critique on simple theorem involving compositions of functions

Tags: functions

Problem statement, as written:

Let $g\colon B\rightarrow C$ and $h\colon B\rightarrow C$ be functions. Suppose that $g\circ f = h\circ f$ for every function $f\colon A\rightarrow B$. Prove that $g=h$.

Supose, to the contrary, that $g\ne h$. Then there is some $b_0 \in B$ such that $g(b_0) \ne h(b_0)$. Let $f_0\colon A\rightarrow B$ be a surjective function. Then $\exists a_0\in A$ such that $b_0 = f(a_0)$. As such, since $g\circ f_0 = h\circ f_0$ by hypothesis, $g(f(a_0)) = g(b_0) = h(f(a_0)) = h(b_0)$. This implies, in particular, that $g(b_0) = h(b_0)$, a contradiction. Hence, it must be the case that $g=h$.

Comment: Yes, you have to assume that $A$ is non-empty.

Comment: I would read that as an implicit universal quantification over $A$.

Comment: You cannot really assume that a surjection $f_0: A \to B$ exists.  For example take $A=\{ 1,2\} $ and $B=\{1,2,3\}$.  However, you do not need to.  Define $f_0(a) = b_0 $ for all $a \in A$ (assuming $A$ is non-empty).  Then your argument works.